# Simple float calculation in C resulting in -nan coming back as a value

Tags: c, cs50, readability

I'm writing a simple program for calculating the readability of a text, and when calculating the average, I am getting an odd result back: "-nan". It's what comes back for both float calculation functions at the bottom of my code, and when I calculate the index in the main function, I get a negative number back. This should be impossible since none of the numbers being divided are negative. Anyone know what -nan means or how I can remedy this?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters (string text);
int count_words (string text);
int count_sentences (string text);
float avg_letters (int lettercount, int wordcount);
float avg_sents (int wordcount, int sentcount);


int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int lettercount = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int sentcount = 0;
    float S = 0;
    float L = 0;

    count_letters (text);
    count_words (text);
    count_sentences (text);
    avg_letters (lettercount, wordcount);
    avg_sents (wordcount, sentcount);

    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    printf("%f\n", index);
}

//Counts letters in entire text
int count_letters (string text)
{
    int lettercount = 0;
    for (int i=0, n = strlen(text); i<n; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] > 64 && text[i] < 91) || (text[i] > 96 && text[i] < 123))
        {
            lettercount ++;
        }
    }
    printf ("%i\n", lettercount);
    return lettercount;
}

//Counts words in text
int count_words (string text)
{
    int wordcount = 0;
    for (int i=0, n = strlen(text); i<n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == 32)
        {
            wordcount ++;
        }
    }
    wordcount += 1;
    printf ("%i\n", wordcount);
    return wordcount;
}

//Counts sentences in text
int count_sentences (string text)
{
    int sentcount = 0;
    for (int i=0, n = strlen(text); i<n; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] == 33) || (text[i] == 63) || (text[i] == 46))
        {
            sentcount ++;
        }
    }
    printf ("%i\n", sentcount);
    return sentcount;
}

//Averages letters per 100 words
float avg_letters (int lettercount, int wordcount)
{
    float L = ((float) lettercount / wordcount) * 100;
    printf("%f\n", L);
    return L;
}

//Averages sentences per 100 words
float avg_sents (int wordcount, int sentcount)
{
    float S = ((float) sentcount / wordcount) * 100;
    printf("%f\n", S);
    return S;
}
```

Comment: You're never assigning the return values of the functions to the variables.

Comment: `lettercount / wordcount` divides by `0`, since `wordcount` is `0`.

Comment: `nan` means *not a number*. You can get that by taking the square root of a negative number, for example. But in your case, you got it by dividing 0 by 0, which is indeterminate, and therefore not a number.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! I didn't realize that's what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the variables.

```
lettercount = count_letters (text);
wordcount = count_words (text);
sentcount = count_sentences (text);
L = avg_letters (lettercount, wordcount);
S = avg_sents (wordcount, sentcount);
```

Since you never assigned them, they all still have the `0` values that you initialize them with, so you divided `0` by `0` in `avg_letters` and `avg_sents`. This produces `nan`, which stands for `not a number`.